# HTTP POST with compressed JSON python returns 200 code but no data posted to website

Tags: python, json, gzip, python-2.x

**Summarize the problem**: Uncompressed JSON payload updates successfully. However, compressed JSON fails to upload to the website.(using Python requests module)

2.
I am trying to POST comparatively large JSON data(1 MB +) to a website
I wish to compress the JSON data(stream) and post it to a wesite. The catch is- compressed JSON returns success code, but data is not reflected on the website.
On the contrary, the same JSON data is making through when not compressed.

3.
**When appropriate, show some code:**

**Works fine**:

payload without compression - goes though to website without issues:

```
payload={"eventType": "check", "status": "Fail","testCategory": "Test"}
headers = {‘Content-Type’: ‘application/json’,‘X-Insert-Key’: ‘XXXXXXX’}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

**NOT working**

the payload that is compressed not making it to the website:

```
payload={"eventType": "check", "status": "Fail","testCategory": "Test"}
headers = {‘Content-Type’: ‘application/json’,‘X-Insert-Key’: ‘XXXXXXX’, ‘Content-Encoding’:‘gzip’}
request_body = zlib.compress(json.dumps(payload))
r = requests.post(url, data=request_body, headers=headers)
```

I am banging my head around but it seems I am missing on something subtle. Any help/tips will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing - ‘Content-Encoding’:‘gzip’} to ‘Content-Encoding’:‘deflate’} fixed the issue for me
Note: This answer is specific to New  Relic custom events